# Error During JSON Array Filter Operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This one is killing me: I'm filtering an array of JSON objects based on one or more properties of each array element. Because the filter expression changes each iteration, I use `vm.runInNewContext()` (instead of the dreaded `eval()`) to evaluate a continually changing filter expression string like this:

```
filteredArray = originalArray.filter(
   vm.runInNewContext("(row) => {return " + filterExpression + "}"));
```

I've verified (via `console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredArray))`) that this definitely achieves the desired filtering.

Now here's the crazy part: I tried to add some code immeditely following this to remove certain properties of each element of `filteredArray` like this:

```
filteredArray.forEach((row) => { delete row.Attribute });
```

Again, this works fine, further filtering down `filteredArray`, UNLESS `row.Attribute` is a string property that I filtered on in the first code block AND that previous filtering included the string operators `.includes()`, `.startsWith()` or `.endsWith()`. In these cases, the original filtering (first code block) fails, throwing the error **Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined** (or **'startsWith'** or **'endsWith'**, depending on what was in `filterExpression`).

In other words, something going on in the SECOND code block somehow "reaches back" and causes the FIRST code block to fail (when it otherwise would succeed if the second block was not there).

Anybody ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Maybe something strange about the way `vm.runInNewContext` works. Could you, instead of using a `filterExpression`, have the whole of the filter functions as variables?

Comment: Here's a fiddle to explain what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/vLr59ufg/3/

Comment: Thanks, I had thought about doing something like that. The only challenge is that there are 9 possible filter criteria, and I can have anywhere from 1 to all 9 of them in a given operation, combined with && or ||, so that's a huge number of potential combos to pre-code. However, much as it pains me from an efficiency standpoint, I suppose I could decompose any comination by successively re-filtering the results, one filter criterion at a time. (And I think you're onto something there about `vm.runInNewContext` - some very black magic going on there.)